# prerequisites for serre's FAC?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

Is the knowledge of undergraduate's basic algebra and general topology enough to reading FAC?
Do I need learn some algebraic topology and homological algebra, commutative algebra, or several complex function prior to reading this paper?
Any textbook/reference recommendations?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9):

The requirements from homological and commutative algebra become more serious as the paper goes on; I count 27 references to [Cartan-Eilenberg](https://archive.org/details/homologicalalgeb033541mbp), for example. You also want to know something about varieties — it seems hopeless to try and study sheaves on them otherwise.

You're fortunate in that [Andrew McLennan has been writing a book](https://andymclennan.droppages.com/fac_trans.pdf) that covers much of the background needed and ends with an English translation of FAC. I don't think you necessarily want to take the time to read all available background before diving into the paper, but it's a rare luxury to have a reference tuned to your specific need.

One plan would be to learn some basic algebraic geometry — say an undergraduate course as laid out in the books of Smith, Reid, Hassett, etc. — and then try to get what you can out of Serre's paper with McLennan's help.

Comment: whoa!! I had an english translation of FAC, but I never heard of the above mentioned book. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: OMG！the book you recommend is absolutely i need!thank you very much!

Comment: and finally,economists begin to learning algebraic geometry,this is to my surprise!?

Comment: @PeterPolo He does give some explanation in preface.

Comment: @Krish I think it's relatively new — I only learned about it from Vakil's latest blog post.

Comment: @Hoot, the link for Andrew McLennan's book seems to be down? Could you please repost it?

Comment: I've fixed the link to Andrew McLennan's translation. If this one stops working in the future, one backup option would be the other links in the [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14404/serres-fac-in-english) discussing translations of FAC.